# enumerate не работает с for

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for

```
i=[]
for index, value in list(enumerate('pyjspy')):
    if value =='py':
        i.append(index)
print(i)
```

Этот код должен добавлять индексы вхождения `'py'` из строки `'pyjspy'` в список `i`, после чего вывести `i` с помощью `print` .
Почему список `i` всегда пустой?

Comment: И вправду, какие-то рукожопы этот python делали, нечё не работает

Answer (score 6):

## Что делает enumerate?

Если `range()` позволяет получить только индексы элементов списка, то `enumerate()` – сразу индекс элемента и его значение.

Таким образом `list(enumerate('pyjspy'))` будет выводить каждый символ из строки и его индекс:

```py
for index, value in list(enumerate('pyjspy')):
    print(index, value)
```

Выводит

```
0 p
1 y
2 j
3 s
4 p
5 y
```

Также во всём этом можно убедиться, если посмотреть на значение `list(enumerate('pyjspy'))`:

```py
print(list(enumerate('pyjspy')))
```

Выводит:

```
[(0, 'p'), (1, 'y'), (2, 'j'), (3, 's'), (4, 'p'), (5, 'y')]
```

## Как питон итерируется по строкам?

Всё это происходит от того, как питон итерирует строки:

```py
for i in 'pyjspy':
    print(i)
```

Выводит:

```
p
y
j
s
p
y
```

## Вывод

В итоге, `i` всегда оказывается пустым, т.к. `value` всегда принимает значение одного символа, соответственно, при сравнении `value` с `'py'` условие никогда не будет выполняться, вследствие ничего не добавляя в `i`.

## Нахождение подстроки в строке

#### Регулярные выражения

Наиболее краткий способ - использовать регулярных выражений, из встроенного модуля [`re`](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/):

```py
from re import finditer
i = []
for match in finditer('py', 'pyjspy'):
    i.append(match.start())
print(i)
```

Выведет:

```
[0, 4]
```

В данном случае `finditer` находит все совпадения вашей подстроки в строке, и выдаёт их вам, единственное, что осталось сделать - записать их в `i`.
Минус: пересекающиеся строки не будут захвачены:
Например, если вы попытаетесь найти `'aba'` в `'ababa'`, то получите только `0`

#### Находить с помощью `str.rfind`

Можно находить подстроку с помощью встроенного метода строки - `rfind`
Он выдаёт индекс последнего вхождения подстроки и `-1`, если подстрока не найдена, также можно ограничивать, где будет происходить поиск - первый и последний индекс.

```py
s = 'pyjspy'
i = []
last_index = len(s)
while True:
    last_index = s.rfind('py', 0, last_index)

    if last_index == -1:
        break

    i.append(last_index)
print(i)
```

Выводит:

```
[4, 0]
```

Индексы в списке будут в порядке убывания.
Данный способ тоже не будет находить пересекающиеся строки, но его можно изменить, чтобы он проходился по каждому индексу, таким образом, захватывая и пересекающиеся строки.

#### Находить с помощью `str.find`

Как с `str.rfind`, только находит первое вхождение.

```py
i = []
sub = 'py'
s = 'pyjspy'
last_index = 0
while True:
    last_index = s.find(sub, last_index)
    if last_index == -1:
        break
    i.append(last_index)
    last_index += len(sub)
print(i)
```

Выводит:

```
[0, 4]
```

Этот способ тоже не захватывает пересекающиеся подстроки, и его тоже можно изменить, чтобы захватвал.

#### Находить с помощью срезов

В данном случае мы будем использовать срезы `[<начальный индекс>:<конечный индекс + 1>]`, т.е. `'abcd'[0:2] == 'ab'`

```py
s = 'pyjspy'
i = []
for index in range(len(s)):
    if s[index:index+2] == 'py':
        i.append(index)
print(i)
```

Выводит:

```
[0, 4]
```

Этот способ будет чуть медленнее, т.к. перебирает каждую пару ближних символов, зато справится с нахождением пересекающихся подстрок.

## Дополнительная информация

**Итерация** - это общий термин для взятия каждого элемента чего-либо, одного за другим. Каждый раз, когда вы используете цикл, явный или неявный, чтобы пройти через группу элементов, это итерация.

Comment: @PyPy если вам помог этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

как вариант

```
text = 'pyjspy'
list_i = []

for index, value in enumerate(text):
    if text[index:index+2] =='py':
        list_i.append(index)
        
print(list_i)
```

Comment: @Betensis вы пробовали запустить мой пример ?

Comment: @Betensis, выходить будет, но `'ab'[0:10] == 'ab'`

Comment: @0dminnimda что такое `ab`  и что такое `10` ?

Comment: @S.Nick, строка .. суть в том, что если при срезе выйти за пределы последовательности, это не спровоцирует ошибку, можно пример с массивом: `[0, 1, 2][0:10] == [0, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

Список пустой потому, что ваша строка будет разбита на буквы, и `value =='py'` никогда не сработает.

Для поиска подстрок можно самому итерироваться по подстрокам. Ну или через регексп.

```
text = 'pyjspy'
search = 'py'

i=[]
for index in range(len(text)-len(search)+1):
    if text[index:index+len(search)] == search:
        i.append(index)
print(i)

# альтернативный метод
import re
x = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(search, text)]
print(x)
```